# Visual Effects not working on my Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Video

Tags: 10.10, drivers, video, compiz

My video card is Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated and the custom visual effects don't work at all! Is it due to the VGA? How can I get visual effects to work?

Comment: Please run **glxinfo** and see if one of the first lines that says Direct Rending says YES. If you do not have glxinfo install the `mesa-utils` package.

Comment: What happens when the effects "don't work"? Is there an error message? Are they slow? What are you doing to try to enable them?

Answer (score 1):

if compiz doesn't work with your chipset, then visual effects WILL fail.  if compiz does work with your chipset and the acceleration is poor(read as in software), you may realise that it sort of works, but the effects are really choppy.  i have used intel chipsets and had compiz work, but with choppy effects.

an acer aspire netbook with onboard intel and shared video ram is a directly pertinent use case that i have worked through.  some effects work okay, others introduce too much overhead and make the desktop nigh on unusable.